# How to make multiple global variables read-only for other modules in C?

Tags: c

Let's say I have moduleA.c moduleB.c and moduleC.c, and modules B and C need to read variables from moduleA.h, but I want to prevent them from write these variables, only A can.

After looking for a while, the only solution I found would be to use "get" functions, but I certainly have many of those variables. Is there any faster way than creating a "get" function for each variable?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using global variables in the first place? There are alternative approaches, such as using a context object which is passed as a parameter.

Comment: C has no concept for read and write access rights - It has a concept of *visibility*, that is, you can **hide** a variable from access.

Answer (score 6):

Export pointers to those variables and make them const.

```
//moduleA.h
extern const type* const c;
```

```
//moduleA.c
type t;
const type* const c = &t;
type* p = &t;
```

Module A can read the object either through `t`, `c`, or `p`, and can modify it through `t` and `p`, while other modules can only read it through `c`.

Comment: Might want to add about "I certainly have many of those variables." - maybe a `struct`?

Comment: Detail: Other functions can attempt modification with `*c = 42;`, but that is UB - which _may_ allow the values to be modified.  Still this is a very reasonable approach for co-operative code.

Comment: Thats interesting. So I could do this with a pointer to the struct and then being able to read all variables at once but without being able to modify them?

Comment: @chux The pointer is a pointer to const, modification you showed is impossible. The compiler *must* issue a compile error.

Comment: @JorgeS You can use any type you want as long as the exported pointer is a pointer to a const type.

Comment: "modification is impossible" is not backup by the C spec.  Instead  "If an attempt is made to modify an object defined with a const-qualified type through use of an lvalue with non-const-qualified type, the behavior is undefined." C11 §6.7.3 6.  It _might_ modify the value, it might not, it is UB.  C does not require an implementation to provide read-only memory for objects.  If OP needs a stronger guarantee than a compile time warning/error, than another approach is needed.

Comment: Agree that a warning is expected, but that is not an error and code can still compile and run and attempt to modify `*c` with success or failure.  It is UB, not defined behavior for the object to be read-only.

Comment: *"modification is impossible" is not backup by the C spec.* Yes it is, a compiler must issue a diagnostic message 5.1.1.3 §1 for this code: `*c = 42;`.

Comment: The qualifier const was literally created to help programer help with writing. It even has its own name: const-correctness. Sugesting that we cannot rely on const is simply ridiculous. The rest of your comment is a strawman. The object t is not defined with const, so it can be modified.

Comment: Back up your assertion with C specification.  My comments are backed by C spec and are neither ridiculous nor straw-men. Try `const int t = 0;
  const int * const c = &t;
  *(int *)c = 42;
  printf("%d\n", t);`  (no compiler errors)  Even though `c` is a `const char * const`, code successfully changes the value of `t` on many machines, because the code invoked UB with `*(int *)c = 42;`

Comment: @2501: Sadly, §6.7.3 ¶6 is not in a 'constraints' section. A compiler is required to generate a diagnostic when you violate a constraint; it is not formally required to issue a diagnostic if you break a semantic requirement — §5.1.1.3 **Diagnostics** _A conforming implementation shall produce at least one diagnostic message (…) if a preprocessing translation unit or translation unit contains a violation of any syntax rule or constraint, even if the behavior is also explicitly specified as undefined or implementation-defined. Diagnostic messages need not be produced in other circumstances._

Comment: @2501: That said, as a 'quality of implementation' issue, you would reasonably expect a compiler to warn of attempts to modify an object via a pointer to const.

Comment: @chux You're entire argument is a strawman because t isn't defined with const. Arguing that const-correctness is a weak guarantee is absurd. This debate is over.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The definition of constraint: *constraint
restriction, either syntactic or `semantic`, by which the exposition of language elements is
to be interpreted*

Comment: @JonathanLeffler In addition to my previous comment: *6.5.16.1 Simple assignment
**Constraints**
§1 One of the following shall hold:  the left operand has atomic, qualified, or unqualified pointer type, and (considering
the type the left operand would have after lvalue conversion) both operands are
pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types, **and the type pointed
to by the left has all the qualifiers of the type pointed to by the right;*** Thus the diagnostics must be issued.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Furthermore, even the standard itself points this out: *6.5.16.1 Simple assignment §6 EXAMPLE 3 cpp = &p; // constraint violation*

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with implementing properties with C preprocessor macros.

I will start with something you presumably have now — variable access without any restrictions. `peek` and `poke` functions are provided as an example to reflect how are we reading and writing these properties.

```
// module_a.h
//
#ifndef __MODULE_A__H__
#define __MODULE_A__H__

void poke(void);

void *foo;
int bar;
float buzz;

#endif
```

```
// module_a.c
//
#include "module_a.h"

void poke(void) {
    foo = (void*) 0xDEADBABE;
    bar = 314;
    buzz = 2.71828f;
}
```

```
// module_b.h
//
#ifndef __MODULE_B__H__
#define __MODULE_B__H__

void peek(void);

#endif
```

```
// module_b.c
//
#include <stdio.h>
#include "module_b.h"
#include "module_a.h"

void peek(void) {
    printf("%p, %d, %f\n", foo, bar, buzz);
}
```

Now we are going to hide these variables from other modules by moving variable declarations inside `module_a.c`, and declaring them as `static` to change their linkage to internal. Static declarations are only visible within the translation unit they were declared in (e.g. `module_a.c` and everything it includes).

To allow other modules to access these variables, we would create few macros to define and declare getters for each property.

```
// module_a.h
//
#ifndef __MODULE_A__H__
#define __MODULE_A__H__

void poke(void);

#define DECL_PROP(T, name)  \
    T get_##name(void);

#define DEF_PROP(T, name)   \
    T get_##name(void) {    \
        return name;        \
    }

DECL_PROP(void*, foo);
DECL_PROP(int, bar);
DECL_PROP(float, buzz);

#endif
```

```
// module_a.c
//
#include "module_a.h"

static void *foo;
static int bar;
static float buzz;

DEF_PROP(void*, foo);
DEF_PROP(int, bar);
DEF_PROP(float, buzz);

void poke(void) {
    foo = (void*) 0xDEADBABE;
    bar = 314;
    buzz = 2.71828f;
}
```

```
// module_b.c
//
#include <stdio.h>
#include "module_b.h"
#include "module_a.h"

void peek(void) {
    printf("%p, %d, %f\n", get_foo(), get_bar(), get_buzz());
}
```

However, these macros seem to be self-repeating a lot — we have mentioned each of properties three times — twice in the implementation and once in the interface part. Maintaining such construct is very error prone, so let's try to reduce this number by combining getter definition and variable declaration.

```
// module_a.h
//
#ifndef __MODULE_A__H__
#define __MODULE_A__H__

void poke(void);

#define DECL_PROP(T, name)  \
    T get_##name(void);

#define DEF_PROP(T, name)   \
    static T name;          \
                            \
    T get_##name(void) {    \
        return name;        \
    }

DECL_PROP(void*, foo);
DECL_PROP(int, bar);
DECL_PROP(float, buzz);

#endif
```

```
// module_a.c
//
#include "module_a.h"

DEF_PROP(void*, foo);
DEF_PROP(int, bar);
DEF_PROP(float, buzz);

void poke(void) {
    foo = (void*) 0xDEADBABE;
    bar = 314;
    buzz = 2.71828f;
}
```

Now let's reduce this further by combining property definition and declaration together and moving our property macros to separate file to keep module files clean and beautiful.

```
// props.h
//
#ifndef __PROPS__H__
#define __PROPS__H__

#define _DECL_PROP(T, name) \
    T get_##name(void);

#define _DEF_PROP(T, name)  \
    static T name;          \
                            \
    T get_##name(void) {    \
        return name;        \
    }

#define DECL_PROPS(PROPSET) \
    PROPSET(_DECL_PROP)

#define DEF_PROPS(PROPSET)  \
    PROPSET(_DEF_PROP)

#endif
```

```
// module_a.h
//
#ifndef __MODULE_A__H__
#define __MODULE_A__H__

#include "props.h"

void poke(void);


#define I_WANT_MY_PROPS(_)  \
    _(void*, foo);          \
    _(int, bar);            \
    _(float, buzz);

DECL_PROPS(I_WANT_MY_PROPS)

#endif
```

```
// module_a.c
//
#include "module_a.h"

DEF_PROPS(I_WANT_MY_PROPS)

void poke(void) {
    foo = (void*) 0xDEADBABE;
    bar = 314;
    buzz = 2.71828f;
}
```

Now, as a final touch, let's add private setters for these properties and obfuscate names of underlying variables so they would not be accessible directly.

```
// props.h
//
#ifndef __PROPS__H__
#define __PROPS__H__

#define _PROP_VAR_NAME(name)    \
    _private_property_prefix_##name

#define _DECL_PROP(T, name) \
    T get_##name(void);

#define _DEF_PROP(T, name)                  \
    static T _PROP_VAR_NAME(name);          \
                                            \
    T get_##name(void) {                    \
        return _PROP_VAR_NAME(name);        \
    }                                       \
                                            \
    static inline T set_##name(T value) {   \
        _PROP_VAR_NAME(name) = value;       \
                                            \
        return value;                       \
    }

#define DECL_PROPS(PROPSET) \
    PROPSET(_DECL_PROP)

#define DEF_PROPS(PROPSET)  \
    PROPSET(_DEF_PROP)

#endif
```

```
// module_a.c
//
#include "module_a.h"

DEF_PROPS(I_WANT_MY_PROPS)

void poke(void) {
    set_foo((void*) 0xDEADBABE);
    set_bar(314);
    set_buzz(2.71828f);
}
```

Comment: Very interesting approach. I didnt think about using Macros for this functions. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Don't forget to use `static` before `T name;` in `DECL_PRIVATE` so that the name is not visible outside the source file where it is defined.  You'd also face an issue with 'how does another module (where the variable isn't defined) get to see the getter function declarations — as opposed to the definitions shown?'

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, please see updated answer that addresses these concerns

Comment: Interesting — definitely an improvement.  I don't know that `module_a.h` should have the `DEF_PROPS` macro; only `module_c.h` should use those macros.  I'm sure the thinking is to keep related bits of code together, but the requirement is really to keep them apart — no client of the module should care in the slightest about the DEF_PROPS, so they shouldn't be troubled by having to process the code.  You might want to mention that you're using X-Macros (see the C documentation).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, making DEF_PROPS local to `module_a.c` would require to duplicate this macro everywhere props would be declared alongside with proplist, which seems to be the opposite of our deduplication effort. Just think of two different private property lists. Also, these are not X-Macros actually, but rather "parametric X macros", as I am passing the X in instead of littering global preprocessor scope.

Answer (score -1):

There are many schemes you could use.  However, the simplest is allow read/write access from everywhere.

To enforce that only writes can occur in moduleA, look at all the code: make sure that only moduleA is writing and all other modules either don't access it, or only read from the variable.

Answer (score -1):

If you have code like

```
int var1;
char * var2;
// ...
double var20;
```

where all these `varX` are global variables, then you really should start refactoring them away.

One possible (although almost equally "dirty") approach is to combine them in some configuration structure and to only provide a "get" function for this structure.

Of course, if you're only concerned about the time / code it takes to create a get function, well, then I welcome you to the evil magic of the preprocessor:

```
#define DECLARE_GLOBAL(type, name) \
  extern type name;                \
  type get_ ## name(void);

#define DEFINE_GLOBAL(type, name, initial) \
  type name = initial;                     \
  type get_ ## name(void) { return name; }
```

In your header:

```
DECLARE_GLOBAL(int, var1);
```

In your implementation file:

```
DEFINE_GLOBAL(int, var1, 42);
```

Try this at home, but **don't consider it as good practice**.